# R - Referencing values in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, vector

Given the matrix below, how would I find a corresponding value for a row and column name?

E.g. if I want to get the value corresponding to Column "30" and Row "0.25", what would the syntax be? I've figured out numbers[4,2) to reference the absolute position but I need "4" and "2" to be dynamic.

```
numbers <- matrix(c(0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.04,   0.25,
                0,  0,  0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.02,   0.02,   0.02,   0.03,   0.03,   0.04,   0.06,   0.11,   0.23,   0.55,
                0,  0.02,   0.04,   0.05,   0.07,   0.09,   0.11,   0.13,   0.15,   0.17,   0.19,   0.24,   0.37,   0.48,   0.16,
                0,  0.06,   0.12,   0.18,   0.23,   0.28,   0.33,   0.37,   0.41,   0.45,   0.47,   0.49,   0.39,   0.21,   0.03,
                1,  0.92,   0.84,   0.76,   0.69,   0.61,   0.54,   0.47,   0.41,   0.35,   0.29,   0.2,    0.12,   0.04,   0.01),ncol=15,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(numbers) <- c(0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,120,150,200,300)
rownames(numbers) <- c(0,0.25,0.50,0.75,1)
```

Comment: `numbers['0.25', '30']`

Comment: What if I wanted to assign 0.25/30 to variables? 

n <- 0.25
m <- 30
resists[n,m].

Comment: In that case you may do either `n <- 0.25;m <- 30; numbers[as.character(n), as.character(m)]` OR `n <- '0.25';m <- '30';numbers[n, m]`